# Download threejs model to .stl

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl

I came to find this library that downloads stl from threejs.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/exporters/STLExporter.js

I am new to js / threejs, so I was wondering how could I incorporate this within my script, or how to link it as a library or other file.

Please note that the model I want to download is either one built from scratch in threejs or one that I imported as glb/gltb and changed some of its features in threejs.

Thank you.

Comment: I removed the java tag. Java and JavaScript are unrelated and very different languages.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official example that demonstrates the usage of `STLExporter`. I suggest you study the respective source code and use it as a foundation for your own app. You can find the mentioned example right here:

https://threejs.org/examples/misc_exporter_stl

> Please note that the model I want to download is either one built from scratch in threejs or one that I imported as glb/gltb and changed some of its features in threejs.

Please keep in mind that STL has no concept of materials. It only saves the raw geometry data. STL is also unable to export hierarchical information of a scene (e.g. child-parent relationships). So depending on what you are going to change in your scene, it's likely that the respective data can't be exported as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is two implementation for export,ASCII & Binary,

```
        function exportASCII() {

            const result = exporter.parse( mesh );
            saveString( result, 'box.stl' );

        }

        function exportBinary() {

            const result = exporter.parse( mesh, { binary: true } );
            saveArrayBuffer( result, 'box.stl' );

        }
```